# Make http response available to the view when it loads

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am stuck in here for hours and need help. How can I make http request so that it's available to the view when it loads. Currently with the following code, the view loads but the response from the server does not come and have to wait few seconds for it to be available.

***src/app/example.ts***

```
 import { MyApp } from 'app.component';
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Http} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Injectable()
    export class ExampleApis{

        http: any;
        requestURL: string;

        constructor( http:Http ){
            this.http = http;
            this.requestURL = 'https://www.example.com/api';
        }

        locations(){
            return this.http.get( this.requestURL + '/locations/?format=json').map( result => result.json() );
        }

    }
```

***src/pages/places-to-stay/places-to-stay.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ExampleApis } from '../../app/apis';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-places-to-stay',
  templateUrl: 'places-to-stay.html'
})
export class PlacesToStayPage {

  locationsList: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public ExampleApis:ExampleApis) {
    this.regions();
  }

  locations(){
    this.ExampleApis.locations().subscribe( response => {
      this.locationsList = response.results;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is other parts of the code? How are you subscribing to the Observeable from your view?

Comment: @AliBaig please see the update question.

Comment: Does this code compiles? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @AliBaig Yes it compiles properly.

Comment: It does some time to process results on the server, if you want to hide something until the response doesn't come, you can use `*ngIf`. I don't really get the problem. If its just the small delay of response, its normal!

Comment: Use `resolve` function in route to handle this scenario - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html